# How to show image by clicking bullet in javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, css

How can i make bullet show image once it's clicked ? i have created click function to loop all the bullets,i'm not sure why its still not working did i declare kind of variable wrong ? or the code in function is wrong? please take a look at my code.

```js
var slideShow = (function () {
    var slideImages = document.getElementsByClassName("slide");
    var slideBullets = document.getElementsByClassName("bullets");
    var current = 0;

    function reset() {        
        for (var i = 0; i < slideImages.length; i++) {
            slideImages[i].style.display = 'none';
        }
    };

    function showImages() {
        for (var i = 0; i < slideImages.length; i++) {
            slideImages[0].style.display = 'block';
        }
    };
    function showBulletsImages() {
        for (var i = 0; i < slideBullets.length; i++) {
            slideBullets[i].addEventListener("click", function () {
                reset();
                slideImages[i].style.display = 'block';
                current = i;
            });
        }
    };

    return {
        reset: reset(),
        showImages: showImages(),
        showBulletsImages: showBulletsImages()
    };
})();
```

```css
#slideshow {
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}

#slide1 {
    background-image: url(https://preview.ibb.co/mV3TR7/1.jpg);
}

#slide2 {
    background-image: url(https://preview.ibb.co/bSCBeS/2.jpg);
}

#slide3 {
    background-image: url(https://preview.ibb.co/kgG9Yn/3.jpg);
}

.slide {
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: center;
    background-size: 800px 400px;
    width: 800px;
    height: 400px;
    margin: auto;
    margin-top: 40px;
}

.slide-contain {
    position: absolute;
    left: 50%;
    bottom: 50%;
    transform: translate3d(-50%,-50%,0);
    text-align: center;
}

.slide-contain span {
    color: white;
}


/*bullets*/
#slidebullet {
    position: relative;
    top: -30px;
    text-align: center;
}

.bullets {
    display: inline-block;
    background-color: gray;
    width: 15px;
    height: 15px;
    border-radius: 10px;
    cursor: pointer;
    transition: background-color 0.6s ease;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="en" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title></title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="index.css" />
</head>
<body>
  
    <div id="slideshow">

        <div id="slide1" class="slide">
            <div class="slide-contain">
                <span>Image One</span>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div id="slide2" class="slide">
            <div class="slide-contain">
                <span>Image Two</span>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div id="slide3" class="slide">
            <div class="slide-contain">
                <span>Image Three</span>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div id="slidebullet">
            <div id="bullet1" class="bullets"></div>
            <div id="bullet2" class="bullets"></div>
            <div id="bullet3" class="bullets"></div>
        </div>

        <div id="arrow-left" class="arrow"></div>
        <div id="arrow-right" class="arrow"></div>
    </div>
    <script src="jquery.js"></script>
    <script src="index.js"></script>
    <script>

    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

If any one would like to give me some advice or edit my code i will appreciate it thank you.

Comment: Best Place for code reviews is here https://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Please change your question title, your question title says that you don't trust the SO community.....

Comment: Okay you meant, you need help with your code since it doesn't work. Check out my answer below. It should solve your problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Problem in your code is, the scope of the loop variable `i` in the function `showBulletsImages`

It is better to use `let` instead of `var` to define index variables in `for` loops, because of such scope issues(like in your case).

Because if you use `var`, when the click function is called the variable `i` is `3` and not the value, that it had when the loop ran.

*Run the code to see the result (if you are using an older browser it might not know the `let` keyword)*

Here is some information on the `let` statement: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/let

And here is a good answer on SO that explains the issue in more detail:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/11444416/1679286

```js
var slideShow = (function () {
    var slideImages = document.getElementsByClassName("slide");
    var slideBullets = document.getElementsByClassName("bullets");
    var current = 0;

    function reset() {        
        for (let i = 0; i < slideImages.length; i++) {
            slideImages[i].style.display = 'none';
        }
    };

    function showImages() {
        for (let i = 0; i < slideImages.length; i++) {
            slideImages[0].style.display = 'block';
        }
    };
    function showBulletsImages() {
        for (let i = 0; i < slideBullets.length; i++) {
            slideBullets[i].addEventListener("click", function () {
                reset();
                slideImages[i].style.display = 'block';
                current = i;
            });
        }
    };

    return {
        reset: reset(),
        showImages: showImages(),
        showBulletsImages: showBulletsImages()
    };
})();
```

```css
#slideshow {
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}

#slide1 {
    background-image: url(https://preview.ibb.co/mV3TR7/1.jpg);
}

#slide2 {
    background-image: url(https://preview.ibb.co/bSCBeS/2.jpg);
}

#slide3 {
    background-image: url(https://preview.ibb.co/kgG9Yn/3.jpg);
}

.slide {
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: center;
    background-size: 800px 400px;
    width: 800px;
    height: 400px;
    margin: auto;
    margin-top: 40px;
}

.slide-contain {
    position: absolute;
    left: 50%;
    bottom: 50%;
    transform: translate3d(-50%,-50%,0);
    text-align: center;
}

.slide-contain span {
    color: white;
}


/*bullets*/
#slidebullet {
    position: relative;
    top: -30px;
    text-align: center;
}

.bullets {
    display: inline-block;
    background-color: gray;
    width: 15px;
    height: 15px;
    border-radius: 10px;
    cursor: pointer;
    transition: background-color 0.6s ease;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="en" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title></title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="index.css" />
</head>
<body>
  
    <div id="slideshow">

        <div id="slide1" class="slide">
            <div class="slide-contain">
                <span>Image One</span>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div id="slide2" class="slide">
            <div class="slide-contain">
                <span>Image Two</span>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div id="slide3" class="slide">
            <div class="slide-contain">
                <span>Image Three</span>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div id="slidebullet">
            <div id="bullet1" class="bullets"></div>
            <div id="bullet2" class="bullets"></div>
            <div id="bullet3" class="bullets"></div>
        </div>

        <div id="arrow-left" class="arrow"></div>
        <div id="arrow-right" class="arrow"></div>
    </div>
    <script src="jquery.js"></script>
    <script src="index.js"></script>
    <script>

    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

**Brief Info**

This function

```
    function showBulletsImages() {
        for (var i = 0; i < slideBullets.length; i++) {
            slideBullets[i].addEventListener("click", function () {
                reset();
                slideImages[i].style.display = 'block';
                current = i;
            });
        }
    }
```

will be interpreted as

```
   function showBulletsImages() {
        var i;
        for (i = 0; i < slideBullets.length; i++) {
            slideBullets[i].addEventListener("click", function () {
                /* the i variable that is used in this function, can be 
                   altered from outside of the function, so with every loop
                   iteration the i variable will increase. So at the end 
                   of the for loop, the i variable will be set in all click
                   functions to the last value of i, which will be 3, since
                   i < slideBullets.length  will end to loop, when i = 3;
                */
                reset();
                slideImages[i].style.display = 'block';
                current = i;
            });
        }
    }
```

On the other hand

```
    function showBulletsImages() {
        for (let i = 0; i < slideBullets.length; i++) {
            /* 
               here the i variable is only valid in the for-block,
               and is unique for each iteration, not like in the var
               case, SO the i, won't be alter by other iterations.
            */
            slideBullets[i].addEventListener("click", function () {
                reset();
                slideImages[i].style.display = 'block';
                current = i;
            });
        }
    }
```

Comment: One more question about what you have said "Because if you use var, when the click function is called the variable i is 3 and not the value, that it had when the loop ran." 
 May you more clarify for me please ? how do you know when the click function is called then variable i is 3 ? @winner_joiner

Comment: @Saranyusocial I updated my answer with some more explaination

Comment: That's very clear and useful for me  i appreciate it thanks for your explanation.